# ASP.Net MVC3 VB.Net Custom LabelFor HtmlHelper not working

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, extension-methods, html-helper

I am trying to create a custom LabelFor helper to apply by default instead of the standard LabelFor helper include in System.Web.Mvc.Html.  I want my LabelFor to take model properties that are PascalCase and make a label that appears as multiple words.  For example the property `FirstName` would appear as "First Name".

I found [this post](http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2010/07/03/asp-net-mvc-labelfor-helper-with-htmlattributes.aspx) that shows how to make a custom LabelFor helper that allows the addition of html attributes.

I recreated this helper in VB.Net and modified it to do what I want, but I am not able to get it to work.

```
Imports System.Linq.Expressions
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Public Module LabelExtensions

    <Extension()> _
    Public Function LabelFor(Of Tmodel, TValue)(html As HtmlHelper(Of Tmodel), expression As Expression(Of Func(Of Tmodel, TValue))) As MvcHtmlString
        Dim metadata As ModelMetadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, html.ViewData)
        Dim htmlFieldName As String = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression)
        Dim labelText As String = If(metadata.DisplayName, If(metadata.PropertyName, htmlFieldName.Split(".").Last()))

        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(labelText) Then Return MvcHtmlString.Empty

        labelText = Regex.Replace(labelText, ".[A-Z]", Function(m) m.ToString()(0) & " " & Char.ToLower(m.ToString()(1)))

        Dim tag As TagBuilder = New TagBuilder("label")
        tag.Attributes.Add("for", html.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId(htmlFieldName))
        tag.SetInnerText(labelText)

        Return MvcHtmlString.Create(tag.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal))
    End Function
```

The sample includes this Module in `Namespace System.Web.Mvc.Html` but when I add the namespace declaration to this module everything in the rest of the project goes haywire.  For example, each of my models has a Primary Key property that is a `Guid` datatype and as soon as I add the namespace above to the module, I get several errors stating that `System.Guid is not defined` among other similar errors.

I've tried to import my project namespace into a view in order to use the custom helper, but then I get an error that says `Overload resolution failed because no 'LabelFor' is most specific for these arguments`.

I'm stuck.  Can anybody help?

I am trying to avoid having to specify a `DisplayName` for every PascalCase property I have in many models.

Comment: I'm not a VB expert, but why you declare it as module and not as static class? Also, adding a namespace might help.. Best regards.

Comment: A VB module is the same thing as a C# static class.  As I mentioned above, I tried adding the namespace `System.Web.Mvc.Html`, but that broke other references to `System` objects in my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do this successfully if I named my extension method something other than LabelFor.  When I named it LabelForPascalCase I was able to use that function in my views.  I think the extension method was not overloading the existing method because they had the same signature.